# SignInManager и фильтры авторизации

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, filter

делаю небольшой учебный проект на ASP.NET MVC. Пытаюсь реализовать регистрацию/авторизацию через SignInManager и фильтр авторизации. Но после выполнения метода SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, default), доступа к action с фильтром все еще нет. Подскажите, что я делаю не так, пожалуйста.

AccountController:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private ApplicationContext _context;
    public AccountController(SignInManager<IdentityUser>signInManager,
    UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, 
    ApplicationContext context) 
{ 
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _userManager = userManager;
    _context = context;
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Registration()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Registration(UserVM userVM)
{
    var findResult = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userVM.Username);

    if (findResult != null)
        return BadRequest(findResult);

    IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser(userVM.Username);
    var creationResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userVM.Password);

    if (creationResult.Succeeded)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, default);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Registration");
}

[Authorize]
public string Index()
{
    return "Yes";
}
```

}

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(opts =>
    {
        opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();

    
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    });
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("CatchAll", "{controller}/{action}/{*data}");
    });
}
}
```

Comment: `if (findResult != null return BadRequest(findResult);` - по-моему, ошибка здесь.

Comment: Нет, я смотрел отладчиком оно мимо этого ифа идёт. Это если что тестовый проект.

Comment: Может быть фильтр [Authorize] не используются с SignInManager? Но что тогда? Потому что юзер в БД добавляется, подпись создается(куки).

Comment: @AlexandrAsh Вот тут может быть то что вам поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1560415/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-asp-mvc/1560418#1560418

Comment: Скажите какой именно статус код отдает сервер, если 401, то вероятно что именно аутентификация/авторизация через куки у вас настроена не полностью, и комментарий выше вам поможет.